# tableview item looping through all items before displaying selected item siwift

Tags: ios, swift

I have an application where I receive information via Alamofire and it gets passed into a tableview. I can further get more details about selected products which is passed to a view controller. this works fine but the issue I have now is when I click a cell to get more details about a particular item it always has to navigate through all other items. If I click an item on cell 5, the detail viewcontroller would display from item 1,2,3,4 then 5 although it does it quickly. I believe once I close the modal like

```
@IBAction func closeModalPressed(_ sender: Any) {

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

it is suppose to remove the previous details. how do I do it to make it show item 5  without looping through 1-4 first

**did select row**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let selected = Services.instance.items[indexPath.row]
        Services.instance.selected = selected        
        let index = IndexPath(row: indexPath.row, section: 0)
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [index], with: .none)
        tableView.selectRow(at: index, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NOTIFY, object: nil)

        performSegue(withIdentifier: TO_DETAILS, sender: nil)

    }
```

Comment: Can you post your code in tableview didSelectRow method?

Comment: @nikBhosale done

Comment: What code do you use to tell the detail controller what to display?

Comment: you are actually reloading rows before performing segue i don't know what's the reason for reloading rows, Due to this reason it is looping through previous cells

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you are doing any api calls or anything in didSelectRowAt, I would suggest try following,

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selected = Services.instance.items[indexPath.row]
    Services.instance.selected = selected        
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NOTIFY, object: nil)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: TO_DETAILS, sender: nil)
}
```

You are unnecessarily reloading row here and asking table view to select same row again which ultimately calls didSelectRowAt.

Comment: still same effect. it still loops through all

Comment: Can you tell me what does notification 'NOTIFY' does? Because there's no code which can loop in above mentioned code.